# jQuery Validate is not working along with Unobtrusive Validation plugin

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a MVC View which is driven by a Model with some Validation attributes. But for a couple of fields where I need to do some custom validation which is not supported with C# attributes.  I am trying to add some rules to the jquery validator.
But when I try to add validate method is not working...

```
$("#Form").validate({

       ignore: [],
       rules: {
           Patients: {
               required: function (element) {
                   return $('#notEnrolled').is(':checked');
               }
           },
           AAA: {
               required: true
           }
       },
       messages: {
           Patients: {
               required: 'Enter Patient Name'
           }

       },

       });
```

When I removing Model attributes and add only Jquery validation it is working fine. But I need a Mixture of both unobtrusive and jquery validation

Comment: You cannot do that is your using `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` What is the validation you want (you need to write you own `ValidationAttribute` if the existing ones do not suit your needs)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke do you mean the only way I have is to Create a custom `ValidationAttribute` on MVC and then apply it to the ViewModel.

Comment: Yes, When you use mvc's client side validation, the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` plugin configures the `$.validator` (I'm guessing that you want a `MustBeTrue` type attribute on a `bool` property?

Comment: Or are you wanting a conditional `[RequiredIf]` attribute - i.e `Patients` is required but only if another checkbox is checked?

Comment: Yes, I want something like `[RequiredIf]`

Comment: You can use a library such as [foolproof](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof). You can also refer [my implementation](https://github.com/stephenmuecke/mvc-conditionalvalidation). And if you want to learn more about writing your own, then [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) is a good guide

Comment: @StephenMuecke In case I Want to write my own Extension method along with the Helper class Do I have to add the same to the script file as `$.validator.addMethod`

Comment: Note its not an 'extension method' (you need to inherit from `ValidationAttribute` and implement `IClietValidatable`). And, yes, you need a `$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add()` script, and a `$.validator.addMethod()` script